# Creating a sidebar with links to google map points

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I am using Derek Ender's map script, it works with google fusion tables to plot locations on a map.

I have it working well, but I got a request to make the sidebar list of locations clickable, so that when you click on a location in the sidebar, the tooltip window for that location will open up on the google map.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this though, tried a few different things but not a whole lot of success yet.

Hoping someone has encountered this before!

Here is a link to my map setup:

http://vepqnv2kjg.esy.es/map.html

Please excuse the weirdo URL, I just threw the files up on a freebie host since the main site is locked behind a VPN.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question, I have updated my answer with the correct info you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add an event to the link you're clicking on...

Here's an example I found.

```
//Map instantiation
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

//Create a marker
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5262405, -0.074549), map: map, title: 'my 2nd title'});

//Create an infowindow object
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

//Add an event listener
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("linkID"), "click", function(ev) {
//Here is the actual link
    infowindow.setContent(marker2);
    infowindow.open(map, marker2);
    map.setCenter(marker2.getPosition());
}
```

You can see adding an event to your links (with a link ID) will allow being able to click and be sent to the corresponding marker.

You should do this in your 'maps_lib.js' inside the `var MapsLib = function (options) {` function.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! My JS skills are rough, I have the code added in, but it is giving me a "myOptions" is not defined.

for the link formation for the sidebar, should it be <a id="linkID">Location</a> ?

Comment: That's because you have map defined already. If you don't understand your own code, you're going to have a rough time. My example is for one marker, rather than X number that you have. Apologies that I cannot assist you more.